# ¿Como hacer que al recargar o cambiar de página web se queden los valores en JavaScript y no se borren?

Tags: javascript

como hago para que se queden los valores al recargar o cambiar de página de mi sitio web los valores se queden guardados en las variables sin PHP. Lo que yo quiero hacer es un modo oscuro, y que al recargar o cambiar de página los valores de  las variables queden igual para así verlo en todas las páginas de mi sitio web.

Comment: Bienvenido, es importante realizar preguntas en base a el documento [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), **te sugerimos editar tu pregunta y agregar lo que has tratado o investigado**. No olvides realizar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) del sitio para conocer su funcionamiento básico, saludos.

Comment: Hola, te invito a leer [ask] y [mcve]. Tu pregunta es muy amplia y basada en opiniones. Sin ejemplo específico de lo que pretendes hacer, es difícil darte una respuesta válida. Igual, mi apreciación es que tal vez estás buscando algo como [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). Saludos

Comment: Eso debe hacerse con PHP, ya sea usando cookies o el localstorage de javascript, pero el problema del localstorage de javascript, creo que es qué los datos guardados solo existiran en la pagina que los guardaste. no estoy muy seguro de esto... que alguien por favor me corrija si no es así no utilizo mucho ni cookies ni localstorage xd

Comment: @Riven, de la documentación de [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage): *Con `sessionStorage` los datos persisten sólo en la ventana/tab que los creó, mientras que con `localStorage` los datos persisten entre ventanas/tabs con el mismo origen.* Saludos

Answer (score 0):

la forma mas simple de hacerlo es con la función localstorage de javascript, con la cual podrás guardar registros persistentes, aunque, lamentablemente este te traerá ciertos problemas en tu frontEnd, ya que debido a que esto sería en tiempo de ejecución por parte del cliente, tu pagina podria cargar en blanco y luego pasar a modo oscuro.

La forma de usar el localStorage sería así:

```
//Como activar el modo oscuro
localStorage.setItem('ModoOscuro', true);

//Como Saber si tiene modo oscuro
if(localStorage.getItem('ModoOscuro') !== undefined && localStorage.getItem('ModoOscuro')){
  //Aqui activar el modo oscuro
}

//Como Eliminar tu modo oscuro
if(localStorage.getItem('ModoOscuro') !== undefined && localStorage.getItem('ModoOscuro')){
  localStorage.removeItem('ModoOscuro');
}
```

Espero te sirva, aunque yo usaría personalmente una cookies, ya que asi sabria antes que se cargue la pagina si es o no modo oscuro.